# SCSS: Group output by media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

In my SCSS, I use different partials for different types of styles.

E.g.

_buttons.scss

```
.btn {
    background:red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .btn {
        font-size:10px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .btn {
        font-size:20px;
    }
}
```

_slideshow.scss

```
.slideshow {
    background:green;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .slideshow {
        font-size:12px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .slideshow {
        font-size:24px;
    }
}
```

screen.scss

```
@import "buttons";
@import "slideshow";
```

Using partials in this way makes it easier to re-use code between projects. For example, if I have a project that doesn't need slideshow, I can just omit _slideshow.scss.

The downside with this method is that media query bits (e.g. `@media only screen and`) get repeated several times in the final CSS, which can quickly result in bloated code.

Is there anyway I can keep my partials as they are, but tell scss to group them together in the output, so all the min-width: 768px are grouped together in one query and all the min-width: 992px are in one query.

E.g. so the output is as follows:

```
.btn {
    background:red;
}

.slideshow {
    background:green;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .btn {
        font-size:10px;
    }

    .slideshow {
        font-size:12px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .btn {
        font-size:20px;
    }

    .slideshow {
        font-size:24px;
    }

}
```

I know I could create a separate partial for each query, and then import them into another sheet and wrap them in a query, but then that starts to become complex to maintain.

Comment: This is a very common feature request for SASS/SCSS. It's being discussed here: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/116

Comment: The fact that you're using media queries to adjust the size of your elements (whether it's font-size or margins or paddings) shows that your design is inefficient.  If all of your elements that needed adjustments were sized in em instead of px, then you would only need to modify the font-size of the body element.

Comment: The font-size thing was just an example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you expect to get a good solution when the provided example is incomplete?  It may be that there *is* a pattern that will work for your needs.

Comment: @cimmanon, if it puts your mind at ease, pretend the OP isn't changing `font-size` but rather `width` or `color` or some other property. What's being changed is not important; the question remains the same: whether to group media queries or to group partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in [future versions](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/116#issuecomment-7355117).

But there's no really so a huge difference between keeping them combined or separated. You could make a test on this site: http://aaronjensen.github.io/media_query_test

There's a difference, but it isn't really a difference that a user will realize.